# Main Stack Exchange network site API

Tags: support, feature-request, api-v2, sites

The original Stack Exchange app has this cool feature where you can browse hot question from the entire network.

But at the current state I am not able to see a “Stack Exchange” site listed in the websites API (I can only see “Meta Stack Exchange”).

Am I missing something? Are you going to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing something.

'Stack Exchange' is not a site in terms of Questions and Answers. It has the sole purpose of offering users (not API consumers) a common place across all network sites. That is why [your network account](https://stackexchange.com/users/19980373/daniel-james-tronca?tab=activity) is there for example, among some other network generic features like Hot Questions and a real-time feed. Further more it offers navigation to informational pages solely catered by Stack Exchange, Inc.

There are a few undocumented (and some can change / be sunsetted at will) features to make sense for automated consumption. I'll list and link to their canonical posts here:

- [How do the Stack Exchange WebSockets work? What are all the options you can send to them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218343)
- [Accessing the Hot Network Questions via the API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275704)

There also is/was `mobile.stackexchange.com` but that [gets decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383026) so I only mention it for historic reasons.